# Unresolved reference: compose in Android app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Am getting the following error in my Jetpack Compose android app

```
CryptoListScreen.kt: (26, 33): Unresolved reference: compose
```

My code looks as follows

```
// import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
@Composable
fun CryptoListScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: CryptoListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state = viewModel.state.value
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(DeepBlue)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(state.cryptos) { crypto ->
                CryptoListItem(
                    crypto = crypto,
                    onItemClick = {
                        android.util.Log.d("TODO-FIXME", "CryptoListScreen-onItemClick----------/${crypto.id}")
                        navController.navigate(
                            Screen.CryptoDetailScreen.route + "/${crypto.id}"
                        )
                })
            }
        }
        if (state.error.isNotBlank()) {
            Text(
                text = state.error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }

        if (state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
    }

}
```

My app/build.gradle looks as below -

```
    dependencies {
    // TODO-FIXME implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$material_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

    // Compose dependencies
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha08"
    // When using a MDC theme
    // TODO-FIXME-DEPRECATE implementation "com.google.android.material:compose-theme-adapter:1.1.16"

    // When using a AppCompat theme
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-appcompat-theme:0.25.1"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.17.0"

    // Coroutines
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0")

    // Dagger - Hilt - For instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation  "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // Dagger - Hilt - For local unit tests
    testImplementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hilt_version"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.2"
}
```

Comment: can put your viewModel here ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the [Hilt navigation dependency for Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation)?

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
}
```