# How to use Hilt in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to create a school project with Jetpack Compose and I try to use Hilt. These are the dependencies I'm using:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00")
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45"
}
```

But when I try to compile the app I get:

> Unresolved reference: compose

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74076859/unresolved-reference-compose-in-android-app), that I should implement `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose` why? I'm not using any navigation. It's a simple app with one activity that contains a LazyColumn with three names. How to solve that?

Comment: Where are the other dependencies? Please put the build.gradle file in full

Comment: There no other dependencies. Which other dependencies are you referring to?

Comment: What is your kotlin version?

Comment: @VahidGarousi 1.8.0 Is that bad?

Comment: please check  my answer and let me know that is your configs are the same?

Comment: did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your added these dependencies in your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'garousi.dev.stackoverflow'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "garousi.dev.stackoverflow"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest"


    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.45'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

your project level `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.45' apply false
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to many dependencies, since I'm not using any of them but Hilt and Compose?

Comment: Please do this and see if the problem is solved or not. If it is solved, we can delete dependencies  you don't need

Comment: if you want to delete some dependencies i will update my answer again

Comment: In order to know where the problem is, it is better to proceed step by step, although it may seem ridiculous, but it has always answered my needs.

Comment: Why do I need to add `"androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"`, since I'm not using navigation at all?

Comment: you can remove it, it is not necessary

Comment: If I remove it, I get the exact same error as in my question. Btw, thanks Vahid for trying to help.

Comment: It is not possible, please check this repo:  https://github.com/VahidGarousi/Stackoverflow

Comment: Don't mention it :). i want to help you :)

Comment: That URL is broken.

Comment: try it again, i am so sorry the repo was private by default.